# SQL Query to remove particular in Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have columns like

[image]

I want only Hour
Month
GB/Month
Gib/Hour

please help me right query in bigquery

Comment: requirements are not clear! you might want to provide more details and at least expected output based on provided sample! also, clarify - is one column or two or ... ?

Comment: In 1 /Hour i want Hour , 1 /Month i want Month , 1 GB/Hour i want GB/Hour @MikhailBerlyant  .

Comment: doesn't really help! show expected output!

Comment: i want to remove 1 / from every column and get only string value @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: Day,
Hour,
Month,
Year,
Cubic Meter/Month,
Day,
GB,
GB/Hour,
GB/Month,
GiB/Hour,
GiB/Month,
Hour,
@MikhailBerlyant

Comment: can please do it by regextract @MikhailBerlyant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below `regexp_replace(col, r'1 /?', '')`

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: can we do it regextract is it possible @MikhailBerlyant